# Remove Prettier round brackets around arrow function statements

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I've written an arrow function and for some reason Prettier thinks it's nice to add some random brackets around the function statement. I like Prettier, but this is bugging the hell out of me due to OCD.

my code:

```
const write = (id, content) =>
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
```

after Prettier:

```
const write = (id, content) =>
  (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content);
```

I couldn't find anything in the extension settings that removes it, is there a way or am I doomed?

Comment: You are missing the point of prettier. Prettier is despite the name not there to make code more aesthetically pleasing it is there to make code *easier to read by making it uniform across a codebase*. It *by design* offers very, very limited configuration options for a reason.

Comment: In addition to @JaredSmith 's comment. It would be to keep consistency when object literals are returned in a concise body scenario. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body. Paraphraising : Returning object literals using the concise body syntax `(params) => { object: literal }` does not work as expected.
This is because JavaScript only sees the arrow function as having a concise body if the token following the arrow is not a left brace. To fix this, wrap the object literal in parentheses

Comment: @JonP This makes sense now, even though I'd still rather have it removed.